# Changing invoice number automatically on workbook close but checking if it has to increase or not

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code below for my workbook that saves the workbook for me and also increases the invoice number by 1 based on the value in a certain cell:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Range("L5").Value = Range("L5").Value + 1
     ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

So cell L5 starts with 1 and right now everytime the workbook is closed it will add +1 to it and save the book, so the next time it opens it will be 2,3,4,5 and so on.

The problem I have is that if someone closes it and open and closes it will keep adding numbers even though that invoice doesn't exit.

Is there anyway it can check a list of value from a column in sheet 2 to see if the current invoice number exists, if it does then add 1 and save, if not then leave the same number and save?

UPDATED SUBMIT CODE WITH CLEARING, SAVING, AND UPDAING INVOCE NUMBER. All cells are locked and protected except the cells in the refTable, those are editable by user but L5 is locked and needs to be editable by the VBA code only, not users.

```
Sub Submit()

Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("B = L5", "C = C5", "D=G5", "E=C10", "F=C9", "G=I9", "H=I10", "I=C13", "J=C14", "K=C15", "L=C16", "M=C17", "N=C18", "O=I13", "P=I14", "Q=I15", "R=I16", "S=I17", "W=H20")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("TravelLog").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value
Next

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox1.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox2.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("U" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("U" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox3.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("V" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("V" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

Range("L5").Value = Range("L5").Value + 1

Range("I9:I10, I13:I17, H20, C5, C9:C10, C13:C18").Select
Selection.ClearContents

    Dim OleObj As OLEObject

    For Each OleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If OleObj.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
            OleObj.Object = False
       End If
    Next OleObj

ThisWorkbook.Save



End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just increase the number and save the workbook whenever you're creating a new invoice as opposed to when you're closing the workbook?

Comment: The reason I increase the number is because that 1 file is being used by many people, so sheet 1 is the form that shows the invoice number, when submit all copied to sheet 2, and clears sheet 1 for next person to work on. So when a new users wants to fill out the form i thought it i would have the new invoice number already there for them.

Comment: Still sounds like it would be better to increase the number when they submit the form instead of when the book is closed.

Comment: AAAA Yes, I just thought about it and came here to post and saw your reply and its what I thought too... So just put the code in the submit button and everytime somone submit it, it will make a new invoice number for the next guy.

Comment: I also put the save workbook code in teh submit button and teh clear form code too is that ok?

Comment: I noticed that when I protect the sheet, the invoice wont change with macro says it is protected and read only. I dont want the users to modify the invoice number manually by accident so i locked it. is there anyway I can work around this?

Comment: That's a question better asked on [SU], but right click on the cells you want them to be able to change and uncheck "Locked".

Comment: I know that, but I want the invoice number to change by itself and not let the user touch it. If i protect the doc then the invoice number cant change.

Comment: Update this question to include preventing the user from changing the value, and I'll post an answer with the code you need.

Comment: I updated the whole code for that button, is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use goto in Workbook_BeforeClose with condition u mentioned like that

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If 'your_condition' = TRUE Then goto do_save
    Range("L5").Value = Range("L5").Value + 1
    do_save:
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```